# Html string set into UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am getting NSString with contain some html tag.
Now I want to set this string into UILabel with working of this html tag

Comment: can you explain your question in detail..

Comment: UILabel does not support HTML tag or richtext. If you want to display HTML you could use UIWebView.

Comment: yes i am using webview but i don't know how to use NSString into webview...

Comment: @aravindhanarvi:::: i am getting data from webservice and in that i get string with some HTML tag and i want to show this string working with this tag look like web page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert HTML to plain text [Download File](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m)

and use

`stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText` function on your string.

Comment: But that is just going to destroy the HTML formatting. The whole point of wanting to use HTML would be to have some basic styles (not using CSS) which is something more than plain text.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) (previously known as NSAttributedString Additions for HTML).

Comment: DTCoreText is a great component. I used it in a project. I had to show more than 10 controls and each of the controls contain html text. So, UIWebview is not a good choice. I used DTCoreText and it is very lightweight.