# Display HTML text in UILabel iphone

Tags: html, xcode, text, uilabel

I am getting a HTML Response from a webservice 
Below is the HTML I am getting in response

```
<p><strong>Topic</strong>Gud mrng.</p>
\n<p><strong>Hello Everybody</strong>: How are you.</p>
\n<p><strong>I am fine</strong>: 1 what about you.</p>
```

I need to display the text in UILabel.

Please help

Comment: use a scroll disabled textView ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use RTLabel library to convert the HTML text. I have used it several times. It works. Here is link to the library and a sample code.

https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel.

Hope I helped.

Comment: one issue that i am facing is, after loading text in `UITableViewCell` when i rotate the device, label text become wider. Same happens for landscape to `portrait` also. Label text becomes narrow. Why? Any workaround?

Answer (score 102):

You can do it without any third-party libraries by using attributed text. I believe it does accept HTML fragments, like the one you're getting, but you may want to wrap it in a complete HTML document so that you can specify CSS:

```
static NSString *html =
    @"<html>"
     "  <head>"
     "    <style type='text/css'>"
     "      body { font: 16pt 'Gill Sans'; color: #1a004b; }"
     "      i { color: #822; }"
     "    </style>"
     "  </head>"
     "  <body>Here is some <i>formatting!</i></body>"
     "</html>";

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
NSError *err = nil;
label.attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
              initWithData: [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                   options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
        documentAttributes: nil
                     error: &err];
if(err)
    NSLog(@"Unable to parse label text: %@", err);
```

Not concise, but you can mop up the mess by adding a category to UILabel:

```
@implementation UILabel (Html)

- (void) setHtml: (NSString*) html
    {
    NSError *err = nil;
    self.attributedText =
        [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                  initWithData: [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                       options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
            documentAttributes: nil
                         error: &err];
    if(err)
        NSLog(@"Unable to parse label text: %@", err);
    }

@end
```

…

```
[someLabel setHtml:@"Be <b>bold!</b>"];
```

Comment: This method doesn't recognize <br> tag. It simply removes elements ahead of <br> tag

Comment: in order for <br> to work you need to set the numberOfLines property for the UILabel to 0:  self.titleLbl.numberOfLines = 0;

Comment: Can you still set font and color when doing this?

`self.attributedText =
            [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                    initWithData: [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                         options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor] }
              documentAttributes: nil
                           error: &err];`
Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @DemandedCross I know your comment is ancient but for others, i think you'd need to use the HTML colour code not UIColor

Comment: `sometText<font color=\"#dc2d4e\">372</font>` doesn't seem work.

Comment: `[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]` is preferred when working with CJK characters, because `NSString` is UTF16 encoded, i.e. `NSUnicodeStringEncoding`

Comment: Good point, it’s possible that UTF16 might actually be faster in _all_ cases. Then again, if you’re working with a string large enough for that performance problem to be even slightly noticeable, you’re probably not putting that text in a `UILabel`!

Answer (score 17):

Swift 4: version

```
extension String {
    func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
        guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
            documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
        return html
    }
}
```

Swift 3: version

```
extension String {
func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
    guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
        data: data,
        options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
    return html
    }
}
```

Swift 2: version

```
extension String {
        func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
            guard let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
            guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
              data: data, 
              options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], 
              documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
            return html
        }
}
```

use it as:

```
label.attributedText = yourStringVar.htmlAttributedString()
```

Comment: My string is: "<b>Pro</b>cess Specialist". Bt its return same what I send to your extension.

Answer (score 6):

### Swift 4

I would rather suggest to extend NSAttributedString with failable convenience init. **String** is not responsible for making **NSAttributedString** by it's nature.

```
extension NSAttributedString {
     convenience init?(html: String) {
        guard let data = html.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(attributedString: attributedString)
    }
}
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(html: "<span> Some <b>bold</b> and <a href='#/userProfile/uname'> Hyperlink </a> and so on </span>")
```

Answer (score 3):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5581178/237838

---

To convert HTML to plain text [Download](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m) File

and use

`stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText` function on your `NSString`

---

OR

You can use [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) (previously known as NSAttributedString Additions for HTML).

Comment: `DTCoreText` build showing compile time error. `'DTHTMLParser.h' file not found`. Any idea?

Comment: `DTCoreText` is not previously known as `NSAttributedString`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the swift 2 version:

```
    let htmlStringData = NSString(string: "<strong>Your HTML String here</strong>").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    guard let html = htmlStringData else { return }

    do {
        let htmlAttrString = try NSAttributedString(data: html, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        yourLabel.attributedText = htmlAttrString
    } catch {
        print("An error occured")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**// Swift 4 compatible | with setting of colour and font options:**

// add following extension to String:

        func htmlAttributed(family: String?, size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString? {

                let sizeInPx = (size * 0.75)

                do {
                  let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
                    "html *" +
                    "{" +
                    "font-size: \(sizeInPx)pt !important;" +
                    "color: \(color.hexString ?? "#000000") !important;" +
                    "font-family: \(family ?? "SFUIText-Regular"), SFUIText !important;" +
                  "}</style> \(self)"

                  guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                    return nil
                  }

                  return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                                options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                          .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                                documentAttributes: nil)
                } catch {
                  print("error: ", error)
                  return nil
                }
              }

        // add following extension to UIColor:

        extension UIColor{

          var hexString:String? {
            if let components = self.cgColor.components {
              let r = components[0]
              let g = components[1]
              let b = components[2]
              return  String(format: "%02X%02X%02X", (Int)(r * 255), (Int)(g * 255), (Int)(b * 255))
            }
            return nil
          }
        }

    // Sample Use:

    yourLabel.attributedText = locationTitle.htmlAttributed(family: yourLabel.font.fontName,
                                                                           size: yourLabel.font.pointSize,
                                                                           color: yourLabel.textColor)
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer in Swift 3:

```
    var str = "<html> ... some html ... </html>"

    let htmlStringData = NSString(string: str).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let html = htmlStringData

    do {
        let htmlAttrString = try? NSAttributedString(
                data: html!,
                options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                documentAttributes: nil
        )
        agreementText.attributedText = htmlAttrString
    } catch {
        print("An error occured")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer in Swift 3:

```
func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
    guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
        data: data,
        options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
    return html
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lately I've been dealing with partial HTML snippets and converting them to attributed strings with the ability to add attributes. Here is my version of the extension

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension String {
  func htmlAttributedString(attributes: [String : Any]? = .none) -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return .none }
    guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
      data: data,
      options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
      documentAttributes: .none) else { return .none }


    html.setAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange(0..<html.length))

    return html
  }
}
```

I call it thus:

```
let attributes = [
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray,
  NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12).traits(traits: .traitItalic)
]

label?.attributedText = partialHTMLString.htmlAttributedString(attributes: attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need to display HTML content on the screen by using UILabel. How to display the HTML content in UILabel we see that in this article. let’s start and achieve it.

[image]

**Objective C:**

```
NSString * htmlString = @"<html><body> <b>  HTML in UILabel is here…. </b> </body></html>";
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString
dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:
NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
UILabel * yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
yourLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

**Swift:**

```
var htmlString = “<html><body> <b>  HTML in UILabel is here…. </b> </body></html>”
var attrStr: NSAttributedString? = nil
do {
 if let data = htmlString.data(using: .unicode) {
 attrStr = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
 }
} catch {
}
var yourLabel = UILabel()
yourLabel.attributedText = attrStr
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/html-text-in-uilabel-ios-f1e0760bcac5