# Change text into strong Bold,Italic etc

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am getting response from API like shown below. I want to show text strong, bold etc. according to API response.

```
message =     {
    <strong>HELLOOOO</strong>
};
   status = 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit and format your questions instead of clarifying in posts ? It will help us to understand

Comment: You need to parse this string, find out correct text formatting and apply the equivalent to the required iOS UI(`UILabel`, `UITextView`) component natively **OR** maybe if this is HTML string you can use this:[RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel). This supports few HTML text formatting options.

Comment: @Amar problem solved using RTLabel and CoreText frame work +1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display HTML text in UILabel iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872257/display-html-text-in-uilabel-iphone)

Comment: @AmitSaini You can upvote the answer to the question I linked above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at using `NSAttributedString` with `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:` and include `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute` with a value of `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` in the options dictionary.

If you need to support older versions of iOS, look at [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText).