# UILabel with HTML content from a website

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing an app that takes some content from a database. I have written the rest api for this database, but because I am working with an existing website that isn't responsive to mobile devices I have to recreate it in iOS.

Unfortunately some of the fields in this database have html strings stored in it. I am trying to present this content in a best possible way without showing the raw html code.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display HTML text in UILabel iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872257/display-html-text-in-uilabel-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UILabel's attributedText property. Convert the HTML string to attributedText or use a project like https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: Thanks a lot. This would do the job.