# Show html inside UITableViewCell with UITextView by resizing cell base on html tag [NOT UILabel!]

Tags: html, swift, uitableview, uitextview

My html tag comes like that from response json

```
"<strong>Volume:<\/strong> 5TB<br \/><strong>Transmission:<\/strong> FTP<br \/><strong>Validity:<\/strong> 1 Year"
```

Actually I can resize `UITableViewCell` if that was label.

But,for `UITextView`,I don't know how to resize it base on my inner html length.The above tag is just an example,it might be more or less.

Any help to show html inside `UITextView` and make the `UITableViewCell` resize based on `UITextView`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872257/display-html-text-in-uilabel-iphone

Comment: Of course i found many answer,everything its in objective-c and i need help with swift because i don't know any obj-c syntax.Why don't u help me instead of posting duplicates.And from my question,there is a tag "swift" included.

Answer (score 0):

to make the cell size based on UITextView

first add the code in View Class

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and just add constraints 8px from all sides to UITextView

and unCheck scrolling Enabled for UITextView

for HTML inside UITextView :

use this library 
https://github.com/amayne/SwiftString

Comment: Umm,thanks for your help.Let me give a try with cell resizing.And I also need some code for implementing html inside UITextView

Comment: It didn't work.If you don't mind,can you provide me with an example.Its more easier for me to learn.

Comment: well, actually I use this library, it's simple, for example textView.text = htmlcode.decodeHTML()

Comment: download the library and copy : ( String+HTML.swift , StringExtensions.swift ) files to your project and set same example like this textView.text = htmlcode.decodeHTML()

Comment: I tried it,but,it didnt work for tag like <strong><br><style>...and it cant show me the same exactly like UIWebView.I tested on UILabel