# How to show an UILable value/text value to HTML string in iOS?

Tags: html, objective-c, nsstring

I've one issue , I  want to show html text in iOS , but I'm getting showing value in one label, how would I shown it in html text? here is what I did

_name.text = tutorial.title;

in **_name.text** I get the value from html parsing.

using this I'm showing html text, but how I pass _name.text value in   this?

```
NSString *my=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <body> <p align='center'> <font color='red' size='3'> <strong> <u> hiii </p> </u> </srong> </font> </body> </html>"];
```

Using this I'm able to show hii or any one message using html but how I add parsing value in this?

Comment: can you explain it further? you want to display html text in a UILabel?

Comment: nop i want to display _name.text label value using html tag  @Joshua

Comment: is this the same thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872257/display-html-text-in-uilabel-iphone

Comment: nop in this showing html value in lable @Joshua

Comment: you want to add label text in html string ?

Comment: yes in the place of hii or any other message @Mahesh

Comment: thnx @Mahesh  it works

Comment: thnx @Joshua ur also work i made wrongly code

Comment: lol @iAsmi ok at least it solves your problem

Comment: yes thnx alot again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //setting text on label
[self.lblStatus setText:@"This is test data"];

//creating string with html format and adding label value in it
NSString *my=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <body> <p align='center'> <font color='red' size='3'> <strong> <u> %@ </p> </u> </srong> </font> </body> </html>",self.lblStatus.text];

//here i'm printing string, you can load it in webview
NSLog(@"My HTml String : %@",my);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is what you were expecting?

```
 NSString *my=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <body> <p align='center'> <font color='red' size='3'> <strong> <u> {textToReplace} </p> </u> </srong> </font> </body> </html>"];

 my = [my stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{textToReplace}" withString:_name.text];


i.e.
 input.text = @"this is a test";

 // perform the stringReplacement
  <html> <body> <p align='center'> <font color='red' size='3'> <strong> <u> this is a test </p> </u> </srong> </font> </body> </html>
```