# How can I bold part of a string from JSON in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a JSON file like this. I have to make bold part of string which is shown in JSON. How can I make parse this JSON?

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images like this. Instead, copy and paste the actual text into the question. And please update your question with what you have tried. There are countless existing examples of parsing JSON in Swift. Try something and update your question and clearly explain what issue you are having.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872257/display-html-text-in-uilabel-iphone

Comment: You said "I have to make bold part of string which is shown in JSON. How can I make parse this JSON?". What does that mean? You want to convert your JSON to strings and then convert the HTML-style tags to mark the text as bold?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you would first want to use `NSJSONSerialization` (Or just `JSONSerialization` in Swift 3) to convert your JSON to an object graph. Once you've done that, you should be able to navigate to the `interestLabel` keys in your data and fetch those strings.

You'll then need to parse those tagged strings somehow. If the only thing you need to do is to find `<b>` and `</b>` bold tags, and no other tags will ever appear in your data then you could probably write your own code. If the strings might have other tags and/or more complex HTML structure then you might want to use an XML/HTML parser. I suggest taking a look at this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios