# How to show html value into label?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting following value from server :

```
        message = "\Ud835\Udc2d\Ud835\Udc1e\Ud835\Udc2c\Ud835\Udc2d";
```

When i show to label it show ????

I am using following code to show :

```
    NSAttributedString *attribute = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[self.message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
lbl.attributedText = attribute;
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display HTML text in UILabel iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872257/display-html-text-in-uilabel-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that they are **not** valid UTF-8 characters. The encoding is probably something other than UTF-8.

[Unicode character d835](http://www.charbase.com/d835-unicode-invalid-character)
[Unicode character dc2d](http://www.charbase.com/dc2d-unicode-invalid-character)
[Unicode character dc1e](http://www.charbase.com/dc1e-unicode-invalid-character)
: